# Why are my Razor pages nav links not working using the default pipeline and configuration

Tags: razor-pages, .net-6.0

I have several links in this base razor project. For some reason my links stopped working. Here is an example:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark"  asp-controller="Contato" asp-action="Contato">Contato</a>
```

My project layout is pretty simple:

[image]

When I run the project and click on the non working link it goes to this url:

```
https://localhost:44372/?action=Contato&controller=Contato
```

However, when I navigate to the correct URL it works fine:

```
https://localhost:44372/Contato
```

I did not change any routing in the program.cs and use the default pipeline stuff:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
```

Any help in this routing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no controllers or actions in a Razor Pages app - only pages. Therefore your anchor tag helpers should use the `asp-page` attribute:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark"  asp-page="/Contato">Contato</a>
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper

Comment: Lol wow, this is awesome. Completely different then MVC or old masterpages. I have lots to learn. Thanks for the help.